# Are all keywords distributed for comma separated variable definitions?

Tags: c++, declaration

In a statement like

```
static int a, b, c;
```

is `static` applied to the definition of all 3 variables or just the first one? What about other keywords like `volatile` or `mutable`.

If the rule is different for different keywords, how does it differ?

For example, I know that `const` is distributed, but pointer is not, e.g.

```
int * a, b;
```

is the same as

```
int * a;
int   b;
```

Note: I tried asking a similar question using `const` as an example instead of `static`, and it was misunderstood. I'd like to know what the **general** rule is for **all** applicable keywords according to the standard.

Let's put it this way. How is a definition/declaration parsed in any case where the variable type specifier consists of multiple words followed by a comma separated list of variables?

Comment: I already advised you to generally avoid that form.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for your input, but that is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All initial typey words apply to all variables or, more properly speaking, declarators. A declarator is a pseudo-expression used in declarations.

For example:

```
static int volatile long a, b[10], *&c, *(*const d)(float);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// typey words

//                       ^  ^^^^^  ^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                       4 declarators
```

Here

- `a` is a static volatile long int
- `b` is a static array[10] of volatile long int
- `c` is a static reference to a pointer to volatile long int
- `d` is a static const pointer to a function (taking float) returning a pointer to a volatile long int

(Also, the order of the initial typey words does not matter.)

---

References:

In C++98 (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) (outdated, I know, but this part of the language hasn't fundamentally changed since then) we have (all emphasis mine):

In **[dcl.dcl]**:

> *simple-declaration:
>
>                    decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* `;`

[...]

> 4. Each *init-declarator* in the *init-declarator-list* contains exactly one *declarator-id*, which is the name declared by that *init-declarator* and hence one of the names declared by the declaration. **The *type-specifiers* (7.1.5) in the *decl-specifier-seq* and the recursive *declarator* structure of the *init-declarator* describe a type (8.3), which is then associated with the name being declared by the *init-declarator*.**

(The standard prefers the term "declaration specifier" over "typey words", but it comes to the same thing.)

This says all the type specifiers are combined with each declarator to form the type of each name being declared. Type specifiers include `const`, `volatile`, `signed`, `unsigned`, as well as all basic types (`void`, `int`, `wchar_t`, ...) and user-defined `class` and `enum` and `typedef` names (see **[dcl.type]**).

Similar language applies to storage class specifiers, which are listed separately (`auto`, `register`, `static`, `extern`, `mutable`) in **[dcl.stc]**:

> 1. [...] **The *storage-class-specifier* applies to the name declared by each *init-declarator* in the list** and not to any names declared by other specifiers. [...]

Similarly, for `typedef` we have (in **[dcl.dcl]**):

> 5. If the *decl-specifier-seq* contains the `typedef` specifier, the declaration is called a *typedef declaration* and **the name of each *init-declarator* is declared to be a *typedef-name***, synonymous with its associated type (7.1.3). [...]

Later on, the chapter about declarators (**[dcl.decl]**) sums up the general principle:

> 2. The two components of a *declaration* are the specifiers (*decl-specifier-seq*; 7.1) and the declarators (*init-declarator-list*). The specifiers indicate the type, storage class or other properties of the objects, functions or typedefs being declared. The declarators specify the names of these objects, functions or typedefs and (optionally) modify the type of the specifiers with operators such as `*` (pointer to) and `()` (function returning). [...]
> 3. Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

Equivalent sections in the current draft:

- [[dcl.dcl]/simple-declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration)
- [[dcl.dcl]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#9)
- [[dcl.dcl]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#10)
- [[dcl.stc]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.stc-1)
- [[dcl.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type)
- [[dcl.decl]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.decl-2)
- [[dcl.decl]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.decl-3)

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward answer. It can be difficult to get one sometimes.

Comment: I would like to see a quote from the standard as well.

Comment: @Chipster Yes, added.

Comment: The occult meaningdcl.decl.2 is that pointers do not distribute: e.g. `int *a,b;` declares a pointer and an int; which is why it should not be written `int* a,b;`. Same for references.